# Error when running a recursive SQL with EntityFramework Core in Mariadb

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mariadb, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I need help on how to use/build the following in Entity Framewore Core (.NET 7).

Among others, i have one class as follows :

```
public class ApplicationModel{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationModel>? Parent { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationModel>? Son { get; set; }
}
```

This reflexive relationship leads to the creation of two tables (I'm using MariaDb/Pomelo 7.0.0-silver.1)

1. Table ApplicationModel
2. Table ApplicationModelApplicationModel

The **goal** is to run a recursive sql to build a tree showing the parent to son relation.

**Please find [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bVXy6R2MtgFXQrdio6mtn3/13) an example of schema and query**.

In the results, you'll find that

- A is the parent of B,
- B is the parent of C and D
- D is parent of E and so on.

**Question** : How may i code this in my Service.cs ?

I've **tried** to (Using [this](https://code-maze.com/efcore-execute-stored-procedures/) and [this](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/953)) create a mariadb procedure (Name GET_DEPENDENCIES, working properly in HeidiSql) but in my Service.cs,

```
         var result = await _dbContext.ApplicationModels
            .FromSqlInterpolated(
            $"CALL `GET_DEPENDENCIES` (1)")
            .ToListAsync();
```

I have the following error :

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: AppName
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.BuildIndexMap(IReadOnlyList`1 columnNames, DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__21_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

May someone please guide me on how to do this **using** or **not** a procedure ?

Regards,

Comment: Try to add `AsNoTracking()` to the query.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast. I've tried but still have the same error.

Comment: Can you update fiddle with exact procedure `GET_DEPENDENCIES` code?

Comment: Post has been updated with the relevant procedure. (I've modified a bit).
It has now GET_DEPENDENCIES and GET_DEPENDENCIES_NAMESONLY which respectively brings back two ApplicationModel entities and two strings. EFCore seem to want only one, thus the problem. I don't know what the solution is but i now understand why you were proposing the AsNoTracking().

Answer (score 1):

I got it ! (probably not the better way)

I created the exact dto i needed

```
public class AppDepDto
{
public string Parent { get; set; }
public string Son { get; set; }
}
```

In the dbContext.cs, i've added a dbset.

```
 public DbSet<AppDepDto> AppDepDtos { get; set; }
```

I had to add in the OnModelCreating the fact it hasn't any key.
([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations))

```
builder
    .Entity<AppDepDto>(
        eb =>
        {
            eb.HasNoKey();
        });
```

Finally, my service just became:

```
public async Task<List<AppDepDto>> GetApplicationDependenciesAsync(int id)
    {
        var liste = await _dbContext.AppDepDtos
            .FromSqlInterpolated($"CALL GET_DEPENDENCIES(1)")
            .ToListAsync();


        return liste;
    }
```

Result are :

```
[   {
    "parent": "A",
    "son": "B"   },   {
    "parent": "B",
    "son": "C"   },   {
    "parent": "B",
    "son": "D"   },   {
    "parent": "D",
    "son": "E"   } ]
```